# load zend-authentication via composer

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php, wamp

I tried to just load zend-authentication, while doing it I get an error:

> require zendframework/zend-authentication Using version ^2.6 for
>   zendframework/zend-authentication ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - Installation request for doctrine/instantiator (locked at 1.1.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

The error shows that the php-version might be wrong, but if I open my wamp startpage on localhost, it shows php version 7.1.9.

Why composer sees the wrong php version and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run composer, you're running php-cli (command line interface), which in your case is a different version from the version apache (WAMP) uses.

What you need to do is go and change the PATH environment variable to target the PHP version you use in WAMP : http://www.forevolve.com/en/articles/2016/10/27/how-to-add-your-php-runtime-directory-to-your-windows-10-path-environment-variable/

Also, make sure composer uses the right version: http://webdevzoom.com/how-to-install-composer-on-windows/#changing-phppath

Comment: very interesting is, that onthe same computer another project works quite fine. I copied the composer.json file from the working project, but it has no effect. So I think it seems not to be a problem with the environment variables (of course I followed the suggested) must be instruction) in the project. Would you have another idea where to search?

Comment: Can you do `php -v` and post the results?

Comment: ok, I was tired of searching and installed an new project where I will copy the other project to